# Prevent Sass from adding number with unit with unitless number

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

I was having some weird problems with the `omega()` function of Bourbon Neat, and so I looked into the [source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/grid/_omega.scss), where I saw the use of the `nth()` function.

After trying out `nth` in SassMeister [I see that all Sass engines produce the same weird output](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/8b352671c54cde4285b4d79a0510dc4b):

**input.scss**

```
.foo {
  content: nth(5n + 3, 1 );
}
```

will produce

**output.css**

```
.foo {
  content: 8n;
}
```

As you can see, it does some strange "math" with my expression. It seems as if Sass is trying to combine the two elements, although it mathematically does not make sense.

This has some bad consequences for mixins using this function, as I would expect `@include omega(4n+4)` to create a pseudo-selector of `4n+4` (skip the first 4, then apply to every 4,8,12...), but it creates `8n` instead (applying to every 8th element).

Is there a logical reason for why this should be so or is this just an early bug that became the spec? And can it be avoided?

Comment: What are you expecting to occur? the `nth` method is supposed to return a particular item from a list.

Comment: Yes, it should return `5n + 3` as the first element.

Comment: For instance, `nth(1 2n + 1 3, 2 );` is asking to return the second element of the list, which is `2n+1`. And it does that, but it transforms it to `3n` in the process.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli is there perhaps an alternative to `nth` that will keep the list elements unaltered? It is a big problem that Sass is trying to add the numbers before returning the list element.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in my original post, and this is the answer for the *second* (how to avoid Sass computing the expression). Feel free to post an additional answer for the first (why Sass does the computation as it does).

What I basically would like to achieve is make Sass treat the expression as a string that is passed unaltered on to plain CSS. Quoting the expression is not a solution, but Sass has two kinds of strings: unquoted and quoted strings.

A co-worker showed me how to create an unquoted string of `3n + 2`:

```
#{3n} + #{2}
```

This creates three strings: `3n`, `+` and `2`, that are then concatenated into one. So the final solution for the code in the question is:

```
.foo {
  content: nth(#{5n} + #{3}, 1 );
}
```